# Uploader won't let me link up an image from Droplr/Cloudfront

Tags: bug, status-norepro, uploader

Droplr gives rather ugly, but still valid URL to an uploaded image *(don't try to follow the link it has expired by now)*:

> http://d1zjcuqflbd5k.cloudfront.net/files/acc_147939/yoKQ?response-content-disposition=inline;%20filename=Screenshot%20on%2010.2.2013%20at%2012.20.01%20AM.png;%20filename*=UTF-8%27%27Screenshot%20on%2010.2.2013%20at%2012.20.01%20AM.png&Expires=1380662677&Signature=QTPB~ONkRImjJYdctY6O4e6n5w6djs5t7RIrnKd0HFICF9hNPhbYYef9TAdj~YSM1NHCTCXhLSlyg5LDfFOxYxVf0gzhBmG2u2C2HIBlncWttWmCCgOeiX87XZeVTXECIC9bkG4HfmOre5zvwaV9KJYHxU2mpcMf~QwRnM7QiUQ_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJTEIOJM3LSMN33SA

But SO image uploader won't let me choose it "from the web", gives "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported" instead (though format is PNG).

Comment: I can't access the image... not surprised that a program can't.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Sorry, I've must have warned that the link is dead now.

Comment: I really don't understand why this is a bug then, or how you expect anyone to check if it is....

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards The link give by Droplr expires quickly. What can I do with it?

Comment: Hi, I'm not going to get in an edit war with you but this is not specific to Stack Overflow so insisting on the tag won't help much... someone else will come along and remove it.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I don't insist on "SO" part, but neither don't want unsolicited edits. Does Meta has to be so unfriendly? I'm trying to help here.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean to come across as unfriendly and apologise if that happened. By posting anywhere on Stack Exchange anyone is able to edit it; there's not much you can do about that I'm afraid. You might consider that people are trying to help?

Comment: @Pavlo I don't want to seem unfriendly either, but if you insist on being consulted on edits, then Stack Exchange is not the place for you.  The family of sites are community edited, so you cannot expect to be solicited.

Comment: "The link give by Droplr expires quickly." Why did you try to post a link that would expire in the first place?

Comment: Didn't have better example, obviously. Wanted to show how link looks like.

Comment: Best I can advice is to ask the team to change the message to something like "This URL does not point to an image" instead of cryptic "format not supported". Maybe it's imgur responsibility though. :)

Comment: Without a link to an actual image, I can't reproduce the issue. If you can provide a link to an image on droplr that can't be uploaded, that's a different matter.

Comment: @Oded [here is one](http://d1zjcuqflbd5k.cloudfront.net/files/acc_144423/vxeP?response-content-disposition=inline;%20filename=iPhone%20image%20on%202013-09-07%20at%2010%3A19%3A07.jpeg;%20filename*=UTF-8%27%27iPhone%20image%20on%202013-09-07%20at%2010%3A19%3A07.jpeg&Expires=1380714738&Signature=YB4cw~KrqZp8ZBo8XOKvV9nIyqiPAKVJAhKC8QyYt-pi4JbYkj8-K0fHpqqoxypOZA6tM582777YyePbWLLFquob93cjx1sMSAiSNjBO7I5wjjLYCu8lgvZlnEyWeLia0z8DtZwEo4Gpx840grA8LX7mWZrjeWu~4ThQlg~sJuA_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJTEIOJM3LSMN33SA). It works even if I right click in Chrome choose "Copy Image" then paste in the upload dialog.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I am getting an `AccessDenied` XML error on that URL.

Comment: @Oded maybe they check Referer. Try copy and paste the URL in the browser. Edit: nope. Oh well, looks like part of the URL is time-dependant key. It's surely their problem, not ours.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yep. Essentially, if they don't give us an image, we can't upload  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, that's not actually an image... when viewing that page, I see this:

[image: screenshot]

---

For future reference, though, when you have an image URL that doesn't end in an image extension, you can use this workaround:

```
http://example.com/someImage
```

changes to

```
http://example.com/someImage?e=.png
```

So that Stack Overflow thinks it's an image and accepts it.

Comment: Unfortunately, link has expired, but the question still stands. Your workaround will do just fine, thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't `?.png` be sufficient?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I don't know, are parameterless values allowed? And can they have a `.` in them?

Comment: @Doorknob yeah, they're allowed. They key would be `".png"` and the value would be `""` (i.e. `params[".png"] == ""`). It's the same as `?.png=`.

Comment: Ah, I must try this when trying to upload an image taken from Chrome awesomescreenshot plugin. That often has a bit of a wobbly moment thinking the image isn't an image.